# Passing data from a gridview to a function

Tags: php, sockets, yii

I have a function in my Server model as :

```
  public function getStatus($server) {
        $socket = @fsockopen($server, '80', $errno, $errstr, 3);
          if($errno == 0) { return true; }
            else { return false;}
        fclose($socket);
    }
```

And in admin.php in the Server view:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'server-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
//'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
    'id',
    'server_name',
    'server_ip',
            array(
                'header'=>'Status',
                'type'=>'html',
                'value'=>$model->getStatus($model->server_ip)?'1':'0',
                 ),
),
)); ?>
```

The mysql column for server_ip is :

```
`server_ip` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0.0.0',
```

I am unable to get the required result with the getStatus function. It returns 0 all the time. When i feed a static value as

```
'value' => $model->getStatus('192.168.1.1')?'1':'0',
```

it works OK.

```
'value' => '$data->server_ip',
```

gives me ip address of each server. But when passed to getStatus, it always returns 1 irrespective of server status.

Can somebody guide me regarding the problem?

Comment: Does "$model->server_ip" contain value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a `CGridView` value expression `$data` refers to the current object/array in your case each `Server`. Therefore you can access `Server` properties and methods using `$data`:

```
'value'=>'$data->getStatus($data->server_ip)?1:0',
```

**EDIT**

The last parameter in `fsockopen()` is an float that represents the timeout in seconds. In order to reduce the loading time:

1. Set timeout to a low number like you did
2. Cache the result of the last status in the database. This can be refreshed periodically.
3. Render the view minus the status and get the status via ajax.

Comment: I changed it to 'value'=>'$data->getStatus($data->server_ip)?1:0', The functionality is ok but the view is rendered differently. Plain page not like yii and no cgridview. Moreover it takes a lot of time.

Comment: i modified the function getStatus and reduced the retry attempts to 1 instead of 3 and now the view is fine. Thanks a lot. Kindly edit you answer suggesting this modification in the getStatus() function too.